# Pyinstaller: how to put all other files except executable in one folder?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

When we use PyInstaller to create an executable, many files are created and stored in the dist folder, along with the executable.

As the following shows.

[image]

It may take a long time for us to find where the executable file is.

Can all other files except the executable be placed in another different folder?

I don't want to use the `--onefile` option to bundle everything into one executable. The `--onefile` flag will make pyinstaller to compresses the file, and every time we run the executable it takes very long time to decompress.

Comment: Could you create a shortcut or symbolic link to the executable so that the user does not need to search for the executable file in the dist directory?

Comment: if I copy it to another computer in different path, shotcut does not work